# Tridion upgrade + in progress Translation Jobs

Tags: translation-manager, upgrade

Reading through the documentation, I was unable to find concrete information on the following. In an upgrade scenario, what happens to the in progress Translation Jobs? More specifically, if we upgrade the TM database (which holds the Translation jobs), and upgrade Tridion + TM, will the new TM service be able to finish the jobs? I'm assuming it will, since he is the one who pings the TMS whether a translation is finished + the TMS remains the same (it's compatible with both TM versions), but I want to be sure.

Of course the safest bet is to have all jobs finished, but this is very unlikely as translation is heavily used.

Comment: I couldn't find the topic either, but I have indeed heard TM upgrades should continue to work after the upgrade assuming the TMS instance hasn't changed and this isn't a move _into_ Cloud. I'll ping some of the team, otherwise leave a comment on the help topic or log a Support ticket for a definitive answer.

Comment: yes, same use case here. actually had issues with this in the past, but seems if you have proper hotfix and setup https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=The-partner-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remote-network-transactions - should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in having in progress Translation Jobs during upgrade. They should work just fine.

But you need to remember to **not run both old and new version of TM service simultaneously**.
This of course happens when people instead of upgrade just install new version on other machine, while having old version still running. This can lead to unpredictable results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, mostly you did answer to your questions.

We did few migrations from SDL Tridion 2013 to SDL Tridion Sites 8.5 with Translation Manager, It worked fine for the in-progress items, I would recommend to having a change freeze during the final cutover DB refresh.

**Note:**

If your Translation Manager database is Cloud-based (AWS or Azure), it must use the same database as Content Manager.